# Swift CSVImporter Cannot use instance member path within property

Tags: swift, csv, import

I am currently trying to import a CSV file using CSVImporter. The github repo says that it is up to date with the current Swift version 3.0. However I am getting an error which I couldn't find a solution to on the internet.

This is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTO6.jpg

This is the github repo: https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter

I would gladly provide anymore information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are unrelated to the CSVImporter library.

The first error happens because you are referring one ivar from another. Essentially this is not valid in Swift:

```
class ABC {
  let hello = "Hello"
  let hello_world = hello + " World" // references 'hello'
}
```

The second error happens because you directly put code into your class. Code in Swift lives in methods or in initialisers, but not directly in a class.

I think this may be what you want:

```
class ViewController {

  let path = "/tmp/blub.csv"

  func load() {
    let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path)
    importer.startImportingRecords ... {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And if this is part of a VC (e.g. you might want to display the CSV in a tableview), you probably want to load the data off the main queue, not in init().

P.S.: Do not only send image links to source code. Copy/paste the relevant source code into the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the successful response, explanation and advice. I will definitly take that into consideration next time.